# Rails : How to stop background job of daemonized sidekiq in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, daemon, sidekiq

I did this command:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -L sidekiq-logfile
```

Now sidekiq can successfully run jobs asynchronously and working perfectly alright, but the thing is how do I stop it?
It has been daemonized.

Should I use ubuntu native commands like kill or something, or sidekiq provides some way to do this from the panel
like http://localhost:3000/sidekiq ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `sidekiqctl` https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Signals#sidekiqctl.

So you need something like:
`bundle exec sidekiqctl stop [pidfile]`

Of course you can use and `kill`, as well.

Comment: Command not found: sidekiqctl
I guess I will just use kill, how can I list the processes with their process id?

Comment: you can get it from sidekiq log

Comment: `ps aux | grep [s]ideki` - second item on the row is the pid